# Can't interate over struct with methods?

Tags: go, struct

My problem is, I have the specified app:

```
myapp
     |- app/main.go
     |- data/a.go
     |- data/b.go
```

In a.go I have struct with methods

```
package data 

type A struct {
    Field_a string
    Field_b string
}

func (a A) SomeMethod() string {
    return "somemethod A"
}
```

In b.go similar:

```
package data

type B struct {
    Field_a string
    Field_b string
}

func (b B) SomeMethod() string {
    return "somemethod B"
}
```

Now I'm refering in main.go in such manner:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "myapp/data"
)

func main() {
    a := data.A{"x","y"} // it works
    b := data.B{"x","y"} // works as well
    c := data.A{"x","y"}.SomeMethod() // works
    d := data.B{"x","y"}.SomeMethod() // works too
    fmt.Printf("a: %T\n",a)
    fmt.Printf("b: %T\n",b)
    fmt.Printf("c: %T\n",c)
    fmt.Printf("d: %T\n",d)
}
```

But the problem which I have is that I want to iterate over these structs from package data and I've tried the following approach:

```
structPool := []struct{
   fielda string
   fieldb string
}{
   data.A{"x","y"}, // data.A{"x","y"}.SometMethod() is valid at this point
   data.B{"x","y"}, // data.B{"x","y"}.SometMethod() is valid at this point
}

for _, structObj := range structPool {
    // can't use here structObj.SomeMethod() - why?
}
```

And I also tried to inititialize this slice `structPool` like this:
`[]interface{}` or `[]struct{}` etc but still compiler does not see methods from these packages inside `for` loop. :(

I will be highly appreciated for any clues. 
Thank in advance

Comment: Ok, I've fixed my example, should be much better now to show my problem (which was fixed)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what you have done has created a new array with field `fielda` and `fieldb`. Its has nothing to do with your structure `A` and `B`. So basically you can't call method `someMethod()`.

```
structPool = []struct {
    fielda string
    fieldb string
}{}
```

You need to implement interface to operate on these struct.

Define a interface like

```
type Common interface {
    someMethod() string
}
```

And your structure `A` and `B` both has implemented this interface.

Now make array of this interface with your data of `A` and `B`.

```
structPool := []Common{
        A{"x", "y"},
        B{"x", "y"},
}
```

Iterate over this array `structObj.someMethod()`

Hope this will help.

See in action if necessary: <kbd>[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Z19GjIC6VHJ)</kbd>

Another example: https://gobyexample.com/interfaces

Other reference: http://www.golangbootcamp.com/book/interfaces

Comment: Thank you! An interface! To be honest I tried it in the beginning but I thought it will be too complicated later to maintain, but it's so easy :/ Ok, lesson learned.